# How to replace nan in Dataframe with NULL in sql server?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, numpy

I've a dataframe and the dataframe values are updated to a table in SQL Server. However, nan values are stored as nan instead of NULL.

What is the correct way to replace with NULL in SQL server

Following is the piece of code.

```
# This does not work (Replacing nan with NULL)
outputData = outputData.where(pd.notnull(outputData), None) 

updatesql = """ update dbo.table set 
                    [col1] = ? ,
                    [col2] = ? ,
                   where t = ?

data = (outputData.reindex(['col1', 'col2', 'dt'] ,axis='columns').to_numpy())
# EXECUTE QUERY AND BIND LIST OF TUPLES
updatecursor.executemany(updatesql, data.tolist())
sql_conn_dev.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using the following

```
updatesql = """ update dbo.table set 
                    [col1] = (case when  [col1= 'nan' then NULL else [col1]  end ), 
                    [col2] = (case when  [col2 = 'nan' then NULL else [col2]  end ) 
                   where t = ? """

data = (outputData.reindex(['dt'] ,axis='columns').to_numpy())
```